# error JsonObjectRequest request

Tags: android, json

**Run this app but has stoped.
I have crashed app android in line:**

```
private void initData(){
    requestData(Config.APP_API_URL + Config.GET_ALL);

    jsonStatusSuccessString =    
getResources().getString(R.string.json_status_success);
    connectionError = getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error);

}

private void requestData(String uri) {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(uri ,null ,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        String status = response.getString("status");
                        if (status.equals(jsonStatusSuccessString)) {
                            progressWheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<PCityData>>() 
{
                            }.getType();

                            pCityDataList =   
gson.fromJson(response.getString("data"), listType);

                            Utils.psLog("City Count : "  + 
pCityDataList.size());
                            if(pCityDataList.size() > 1) {
                                singleLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                updateDisplay();
                            }else{
                                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                singleLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                stopLoading();
                                updateSingleDisplay();
                            }

                            updateGlobalCityList();

                        } else {
                            stopLoading();
                            Utils.psLog("Error in loading CityList.");
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Utils.psErrorLogE("Error in loading CityList.", e);
                        stopLoading();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
```

**but I ended up getting NullPointerException, and here is my code:**

> 05-01 13:27:05.096 6997-6997/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectory E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectory, PID: 6997
>                                                                                  com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:241)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:231)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
>                                                                                      at com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectory.fragments.CitiesListFragment$5.onResponse(CitiesListFragment.java:254)
>                                                                                      at com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectory.fragments.CitiesListFragment$5.onResponse(CitiesListFragment.java:243)
>                                                                                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:72)
>                                                                                      at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
>                                                                                      at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextInt(JsonReader.java:1178)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:239)
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:231) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768) 
>                                                                                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717) 
>                                                                                      at com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectory.fragments.CitiesListFragment$5.onResponse(CitiesListFragment.java:254) 
>                                                                                      at com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectory.fragments.CitiesListFragment$5.onResponse(CitiesListFragment.java:243) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:72) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Like it says here

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "" at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:241) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:231) at

You are getting "" (empty string) in one of your parameters where it's suposed to be a double value

Comment: I don't empty string. Where do I find?